# Python: Write float array to a file

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

What is the cleanest and easiest way to write float array to a file? 
This is what i was trying to do. mylist is array.

```
match = re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", line)
    if match is not None:
        self.deltae = float(match.group(1))
        self.intensity = float(match.group(2))
        mylist = [self.deltae, self.intensity]
        with open("Test.txt", 'w') as myfile:
             for range(sublist) in mylist:
                myfile.write(', '.join(str(item) for item in sublist)+'\n')
        print(mylist)
```

My list looks like that :

```
13.5423     0.0116934333
17.9918     0.0476088508
22.4523     0.0082869379
26.5963     0.00291399
34.1077     0.0222519629
39.0881     0.0027373305
```

[image]

Comment: Is `mylist`  a 2D list?

Comment: Can you show exactly how your `mylist` looks like?

Comment: mylist = [self.deltae, self.intensity]

Comment: so: `[self.deltae, self.intensity, self.deltae, self.intensity,  self.deltae, self.intensity]`?

Comment: self.deltae and self.intensity is values got from parsing file, and those values are put in array mylist  after printgin mylist in cmd it shows like i showed My list looks like that

Comment: is your method not working? do you get an error?

Comment: yep expecting string not float

Comment: thats why i am asking how to write float array into file

Comment: also ... when posting here, if you have an error, always post the full traceback message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `mylist` is a 2-element list, you can use a generator expression:

```
with open("Test.txt", 'a') as myfile:
    myfile.write(', '.join(str(item) for item in mylist)+'\n')
```

or the outdated `map` to map `float` to `str`:

```
with open("Test.txt", 'a') as myfile:
    myfile.write(', '.join(map(str, mylist))+'\n')
```

If `mylist` is defined inside a loop, then you need to run this code inside the same loop to process all rows.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ... is this working for you?

Comment: its working , but it prints only the last number from my array

Comment: and its printing only one float from first columns.

Comment: I don't know how your "array" is, you might have to iterate through it. This code assumes that `mylist` is of the format `[13.5423, 0.0116934333]`. So, it will only print one row ... just tell us what format your array is

Comment: oh srr forgot to tell you , that my array can be any format form 2x1000 and more or less, so i dont know how to act in that situation

Comment: so, you have a list of lists like `[ [13.5423, 0.0116934333], [17.9918, 0.0476088508], ... ]` ?

Comment: ok. I edited my answer to iterate through all rows ... hope it works for you.

Comment: got TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Then `mylist` is not `[ [13.5423, 0.0116934333], [17.9918, 0.0476088508], ... ]` ... we can't help, if you don't give us all the information. please post the result of `print mylist`

Comment: Posted an image, srr i am new to python

Comment: what you posted is not a standard type in Python ... is your print statement inside a `for` loop? what if you do `print len(mylist), type(mylist)`?

Comment: ok, so mylist is a list of 2 elements ... which is what I assumed in my original answer ... Then, somehow in your code, you iterate through something and at each iteration, you define mylist as a 2-element list

Comment: I edited back my answer. I'm afraid I can't do more for you. But I advise you to go through some python tutorials: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: I think problem is that everytime it opens new txt and owerwrite it with new element from my list  and thats why i always have last element

Comment: true ... write 'a' instead of 'w' in the `open`  command ... see last edit

Comment: yeah :-) sorry about that ... this should have been solved a long time ago.

Comment: yes but using this method is a bit clumsy because u have to manualy delete txt all the time if u want to put new array :)